# Referencing a number in a JavaScript multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, dataset

The code I have below uses a number as a dataset in a JavaScript object:

```
spacenum = spacedetails[1];
//Create object for space number
if(spacenum in spaceobj['P1'] == false){
    spaceobj['P1'][spacenum] = {}; // must initialize the sub-object, otherwise will get 'undefined' errors
}
spaceobj['P1'][spacenum]['Vacant'] = spacedetails[2];
spaceobj['P1'][spacenum]['Name'] = spacedetails[3];
spaceobj['P1'][spacenum]['Number'] = spacedetails[4];
spaceobj['P1'][spacenum]['Apartment'] = spacedetails[5];
```

This code goes around in a loop so 'spacenum' starts at 1 and goes up to the late 100s.

I am trying to access the data like so:

```
console.log(spaceobj.P1.11.Vacant);
```

However, the '11' is throwing up errors. I've tried brackets and quotes without any luck.

How can I access the data I want using a number?

Comment: you should be able like so `console.log(spaceobj['P1'][11].Vacant);` if you cant like that, paste the error log from the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript '11' is not a valid variable name. However, because of its dynamic nature you can use:

`console.log(spaceobj.P1["11"].Vacant);`

Alternatively, one can also use:

`console.log(spaceobj["P1"]["11"].Vacant);`

Comment: Thank you so much. Will accept this as soon as I can!

Comment: `P1` is neither a variable name. it's a key.

Comment: True. But the answer still works in this case. Edited my answer to reflect your suggestion. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually your line code below is undefined

> spaceobj['P1']

Be sure your spaceobj['P1'] = false; has value

```
spacenum = 11;
spaceobj = [];
spaceobj['P1'] = false;
spaceobj['P1'][spacenum]= 'A';
spaceobj['P1'][spacenum]= 'B';
```